# Why won't my NSUserDefaults load?

Tags: iphone, load, save, nsuserdefaults

So I have an iphone app that presents a modal view when it starts if the user has not registered. Once they register, it saves a user ID into NSUserDefaults. When the app starts at a later time, it needs to load this user id in the appdelegate file.

```
//Registration.m
NSUserDefaults *savedUID = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[savedUID setObject:UID forKey:@"user_id"];

//AuctionTracAppDelegate.m
NSUserDefaults *savedID = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *uidString = [savedID stringForKey:@"user_id"];
```

My problem is that when I try to load this value at a separate execution, the object I saved is always null. I know for a fact that it is saving the string object correctly. Also, this weird behavior JUST surfaced. This exact code was working earlier, then after working on a totally unrelated file, this code fails. I'm clueless as to what happened. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to call the [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) method.

Comment: Yep. Ran into this one myself the other day.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue!!!! :D

Now I just need to figure out all those memory leaks :o